# Chess engine. Is it ok to pass board object reference to a piece?

Tags: java, chess

I am creating a chess engine. I have Piece interface, Rook, Bishop etc. implements this class. My board is Piece[][] array. Let's say white player wants to move his bishop. I pass coordinate of a destination and a board reference to the bishop. Bishop checks, if destination is on the same diagonal, then it asks the board if there are no any pieces between his position and destination square. Is it ok from OOP point of view to do so? 
Thank you

Comment: It's fine from an OOP standpoint, but might make some advocates of various MVC schemes and whatnot have a conniption.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have a class GameController, it looks for checks, mate, saves history. Would it be better if Bishop checks only if it is on the same diagonal and GameController checks squares between?

Comment: It's usually better if you concentrate similar logic in a single location.  Eg, the Bishop "asks" the board object if there are any pieces it might need to know about, supplying parameters describing what's "interesting", and other pieces would do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit delicate.

### The OOP point of view

From an OOP point of view, one could question whether the Board should be a `Piece[][]` array in the first place. A nice, clean, object-oriented design here would probably involve something like an

```
interface Board {
    Piece get(int r, int c);

    // Should this be here? See below...
    void set(int r, int c, Piece p);
}
```

And then, one crucial question is: Will the Bishop place "itself" on the target position of the given board? Or, focussing on the OOP point: Is the board that is given to the piece *mutable* or is it "read-only"? One could imagine a `MaliciousBishop` class that, when it is given the `Board`, assassinates the opponent's King, by placing itself on the king's position.

From a very high-level, abstract OOP point of view, one could question whether a `Piece` should have any intelligence at all. A `Piece` is a dumb piece of plastic. It does not **know** anything about chess rules. **You** (the player) can place that piece anywhere, either obeying or ignoring the chess rules. So it's certainly not the job of the piece to obey or even check any rules. One could say that *obeying* the rules is what is expected from the *player*, and *enforcing* that the rules are obeyed is the job of a superordinate intelligence (some "ChessGameManager" class, maybe).

A simple approach that **seems to** (!) lend itself for an OO chess implementation is to have classes like

```
abstract class Piece {
    Color getColor() { ... }
    Point getPosition() { ... }

    abstract void doMove(...) { ... }
}

class Bishop extends Piece {
    void doMove(....) { ... }   
}

// + other classes extending "Piece"
```

But note that this may not always be the best approach, and maybe not always sufficient. Particularly, you should have a *very* clear idea about how your `Engine`, your `Board`, your `Piece` and your `Player` classes interact and what their responsibilities are. (After thinking about this for a while, you'll likely come to the conclusion that you'll also want a `Move` class...). In general, checking whether a move is valid is *far* more complex than it looks at the first glance. You mentioned that, for the Bishop move, you check whether the target position is valid and that there are no other pieces are in-between. But the move is still invalid if the move causes the own king to be left in check. This can only be checked by the "engine", and hardly by the piece itself. Other things that people tend to forget (and that involve information about *the whole game state*, and can thus hardly be handled by a single Piece) are [Castling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling) or [En passant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant) moves.

### The chess *engine* point of view

For a chess engine, there are several requirements that make a nice, object oriented approach particularly hard. If your intention is to write an efficient chess engine, then your board will most likely be an array of `long` values that are manipulated with bitwise operations....

(A side note: If you had designed your `Board` class as an **interface**, as suggested above, then you could still keep a nice, high-level, object oriented *view* on this highly performance-optimized representation that is used for the engine itself. My rule of thumb: Always model everything as an interface in the beginning. It's easy to make it more concrete afterwards)

---

So depending on whether you want to write

- a nice, object oriented chess for two human players, with rule checking or
- a chess engine

you might want to tackle some parts of the game design differently.

---

EDIT: You'll certainly stumble on this when you are looking for information about chess (engine) programming, but I'd like to point out that https://www.chessprogramming.org/Main_Page offers a lot of background information. Again: This is not really about the OO design, but more about the nitty gritty bits of chess engines.

Comment: Thank you for a such detailed answer. I didn't mention, that I have GameController class, that checks for hidden checks, mate etc. Now I want to redesign and make all Pieces dumb, so they will control only if they are able to move there, without checking the board(diagonal for bishop). Then GameController will take care of "free way", king safety.

Comment: @user1872329 **Wait**: You said "*Now I want to redesign and make all Pieces dumb*". Don't injudiciously change your design based on such a single answer. Think about what you want to implement (a 2-player game, or an engine?), what you want to focus on (performance, OO design?), and what would be the best solution for your goal. The other answers (*including* the answer that suggested the `...extends Piece` approach) made valid points, and you should **carefully** think about the options. *Not* making the pieces "dumb" can also be OK, but think about the cases that I mentioned (castling etc)

Comment: I am struggling with En Passant now, so it seems a better option to pass game state control to another class. Thank you a lot, again.

Answer (score 1):

From an OOP point of view, the bishop (rook etc...) should be able to say what is a legal turn for him - that is, if given field is on the same diagonal. Also it could tell the board that it cannot "skip" other pieces (IIRC only the knight can do that, so knight could override this).

Then again, no piece can move to a field with another piece of the same color on it, also no move should endanger (check) the king. These constraints should be checked by your GameController class (or some underlying class that encapsulates that logic), because they hold for all pieces.

If GameController checked if target field is empty and then asked the piece if it can move there, the piece itself wouldn't have to know your board array and the common logic would be concentrated in the controller.

Sorry for my poor chess vocabulary :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll change my design

Comment: "*the bishop (rook etc...) should be able to say what is a legal turn for him*" - as mentioned in my answer: This one version of the pure OOP viewpoint. But in order to check whether a move is valid, the rook would have to know other things, e.g. whether the move leaves the own king in check, or whether the move is a Castling move (and thus, whether the own king was moved before). A "nice OOP design" of chess turns out to be harder than it looks at the first glance.

Comment: Yes, what I was trying to say was that the rook/knight/whatever shouldn't bother with checking if they leave the king in check etc. Instead, they should only know the rules that are specific for them - the others are more easily checked by the controller. Your answer was far more elaborate though :)

Answer (score 1):

From the design point of view you have two (or maybe more) options to consider:

1. Board is a kind of rules manager and it should know how pieces can act - there is a limitation - Board has to know every actor, since Chess has limited number of types this is not a problem.
2. Board is only a place holder / coordinate system for pieces. With this approach you can save a lot of code by having abstract class (or interface, like you wrote, but there will be many common attributes between pieces, so abstract class looks better for me) for Piece, and every type of piece will extend/implement it. Example:

   ```
   public abstract class Piece
   {
       private int row;
       private int column; // or other method to store position
       private boolean isBlack // or enum for type  

       // contructor, getters, setters etc...

       public abstract boolean canMove(int newX, int newY);
      /* some other abstract methods if you need */
   }
   ```

   And later

   ```
   public class Bishop extends Piece
   {
         @Override
         public boolean canMove(int newX, int newY)
         {
               if( /*check if new points aare on diagonal */)
                   return true;
               else
                   return false;
         }
    }
    public class Knight extends Piece
    {
         @Override
         public boolean canMove(int newX, int newY)
         {
               if( /*check if L shaped with prev pos */)
                   return true;
               else
                   return false;
         }
    }
   ```

I would choose second option. It is more OOP + it allows more flexibility in storing pieces. In game class you can have methods that takes as argument Piece and pass anything that extends Piece class, Bishops, Knight, etc. and polymorphism will do the job for you. In case of first option you will probably need to use some switch/case.

Of course you will also need to have other classes for players, game state etc.

To answer your question - it is OK to pass board to piece. In my proposition piece knows where it stands, so it only needs to know what is new proposed position to check if it didn't exceed board size and is legal for its type. Since game controller checks for collisions you don't actually need the board?

Comment: Thank you. I will stick with an interface, because I already have it. But it seems, that abstract class would be a better option.

Comment: It's a little bit weird to me, that Piece will have field Board. Because Board contains all pieces and every piece will "know" about the whole board.

Comment: I think it has to know, I am not chess master, but as far as I remember you can't move your own unit on your other own unit, so in `canMove()` you need also check if there is no other piece of same player, so you will need access to other pieces.

Comment: I was thinking, that every piece will control only if it's legal for it to move there, like if it's the same row for a rook etc. Then GameController will "ask" board if there're any pieces between from-square and to-square, if this move will not open some hidden check etc.

Comment: Thats also ok, maybe even better, you wont have bidirectional connection between piece and board. Now I saw you wrote in question that board holds array of pieces, so I remove this from my answer.